# Can't find jetty's root.war

Tags: jetty

I'm trying to build a docker image with my war file and jetty, and the tutorials seem pretty straght forward except for one thing.

```
FROM jetty
ADD mysample.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root.war
EXPOSE 8080
```

but I don't have /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root.war on my system. Brew installed jetty into /usr/local/Cellar/jetty/9.4.8.v20171121 but there isn't a root.war under the path.

I'm running macOS 10.12.6 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the official docker image ...

https://hub.docker.com/_/jetty/

.. the `/var/lib/jetty` path is the `${jetty.base}` directory.

When your `Dockerfile` uses:

```
ADD mysample.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root.war
```

It is taking your `mysample.war` and putting it in `${jetty.base}/webapps/` with the special reserved name `root.war` that uses `contextPath = "/"`.

The locally installed path `/usr/local/Cellar/jetty/9.4.8.v20171121` has nothing to do with your docker image, and its likely not a `${jetty.base}` directory (it looks like a `${jetty.home}` directory path)

If you had used the following instead ...

```
ADD mysample.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/hello.war
```

Then that war would have been deployed to `contextPath = "/hello"`, meaning you would access that via the general url ...

```
<scheme>://<host:port>/<contextPath>/<resourceInWar>
Examples:
    http://localhost:8080/hello/
   https://machine.com/hello/main.css
```

Reference: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/automatic-webapp-deployment.html